# Not able to get farm machine using 'bsub' command

Tags: lsf

I am not able to get farm machine which below command.

```
Command:- "/temp/kfi/farm/bin/bsub -q rnd -R "(OSNAME==Linux) && (OSREL==EE70) && (SFIPLATFORM >= c0100)" -P VIP:11.3:RD:sim -W 4000:00 /usr/bin/xterm"
```

I am trying to get the machine for Load Sharing Facility with config RH version 7. When i try to run above command, Job is just getting queued and not opening xterm window for long time. Am i missing something here?

Comment: Please append the output of these two commands to your question: `bjobs -l <jobid>` and `bhist -l <jobid>`.

Comment: Michale, Its too long and not not allowing me to copy the output.

Comment: You can append it to the question section.